# Calling multiple iterators on xrange objects

Tags: python, iterator, generator

Why does

```
zip(*[xrange(5)]*2)
```

give `[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)]` but

```
zip(*[iter(xrange(5))]*2)
```

give `[(0, 1), (2, 3)]`?

I always though that generator were iterators, so `iter` on a generator was a no-op.

For example,

```
list(iter(xrange(5)))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

is the same as

```
list(xrange(5))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

(The same is true for Python 3, but with `list(zip(` and `range`.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Theres a difference between an *iterable* and an *iterator*.  You can use `iter(x)` to build an iterator for any given iterable `x`.  An iterator encapsulates the state of an iteration, while an iterable is something you can create a new iterator from.

`xrange()` is an iterable, but not an iterator.  You can create multiple iterators for a single `xrange()` object, and each of it has its own position.

The `zip()` function implicitly calls `iter()` on each of its arguments.  For `zip(*[xrange(5)]*2)`, this will create two iterators for the same `xrange()` objects, each with its own iteration state.  For `zip(*[iter(xrange(5))]*2)`, you are already passing in the same iterator twice.  Calling `iter()` on an iterator simply returns the iterator itself, so that you end up with only a single iterator in this case.

Comment: Ah hah - xrange objects are immutable, and can be repeatedly iterated over without exhausting.

Comment: @Peter DeGlopper: I don't think this has anything to do with immutability, just the fact that `[an_object]*2` returns a list with two references to the same object - in this question, the same iterator. `range(5)`, which returns a (mutable) list, behaves the same as `xrange(5)` here.

Comment: But there also two references to the same `xrange` object in the `[xrange(5)]*2` list, which is why if it were in fact an iterator it would behave as the OP expected. You're right that immutability isn't really the key point - just that iterating over it doesn't change its state.

Comment: The key difference is that in the first example, two separate iterator instances are created by `zip` - one for each *iterable* passed into it.  In the second example, two *iterators* are passed to `zip`, and so when `zip` calls `iter()` on them it gets the iterator back.  Now since both of these iterators really reference the same iterator, the state of that iterator very much comes into play! :)

Comment: "in the first example, two separate iterator instances are created by zip - one for each iterable passed into it" - The effect is as you describe, but don't think it's quite correct to say "one for each iterable passed into it". It's actually the same iterable - it just produces independent iterators when iterated over twice. `zip` gets two references to the same iterable, and iterates over both of them. The same thing happens in the second example, just that the iterable `zip` receives is actually an iterator and can be exhausted while `xrange` objects cannot. Splitting hairs, possibly.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  Same iterable - I guess the important part is that `zip` creates two separate iterators from it.  I think I understand your first comment better now, perhaps your meaning was more along the lines of "xrange objects can  have many iterators created from them without the iterable itself exhausting." The difference between iterator and iterable is not always clear to me so exercises and discussion like this help me to better understand. Thank you :) And thanks to Sven for the clear, informative answer.

Comment: Sven's answer is indeed quality. The only reason I kept quibbling over the terminology is that I was initially confused myself, and the iterator/iterable distinction is what made it make sense to me.